# Oracle - why is this paging code not using the stopkey optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

I've run across a strange situation regarding a paginated query and the stopkey optimization on 11G (I've been able to reproduce on full 11G as well as XE installs). I'm using the alexa top 1M sites for a test database with (id, url, page) as columns and the id column indexed. The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT raw_sql_.*, rownum raw_rnum_
  FROM (select id, url, page from alexa_data order by id asc) raw_sql_
)
WHERE raw_rnum_ between 800001 and 800010;
```

Generates this execution plan:

[image]

While this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT raw_sql_.*, rownum raw_rnum_
  FROM (select id, url, page from alexa_data order by id asc) raw_sql_
)
WHERE raw_rnum_ >= 800001 and rownum <= 10;
```

Generated an execution plan with the STOPKEY optimization:

[image]

The only difference between the two is `WHERE raw_rnum_ between 800001 and 800010;` 
vs `WHERE raw_rnum_ >= 800001 and rownum <= 10`.

From what I can see these queries behave exactly the same otherwise. Does anyone know why the stopkey optimization is missing from the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't think of it as of a bug.

I would assume that optimizer is unable to push your `raw_rnum_ between 800001 and 800010` deeper into subquery, as it would result in `where rownum >800001 and rownum < 800010`, which [obviously](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:948366252775) doesn't make any sense.

So it treats your `raw_rnum_` as a plain number column, probably unable to assume that initial predicate on `raw_rnum_` would filter out only 10 rows.

Comment: I agree, I actually edited out the word bug when I re-read the post after submitting =)